# Why swift generics Any type cannot match anything?

Tags: swift, generics

I've no idea how to explain. So I give you code like this.

```
class A<T, P> {

}

class B<T> {
    var lotsOfA: [A<T, Any>] = []

    func addA(_ a: A<T, Any>) {}
}

let a = A<Int, Bool>()
let b = B<Int>()

b.addA(a)
```

I think `A<Int, Any>` is kind of `A<Int, Any>` . But get error link this:

error: Playground.playground:14:8: error: cannot convert value of type `'A<Int, Bool>'` to expected argument type `'A<Int, Any>'`

Comment: Generic types are not covarient in Swift. Even if `Bool` is a subtype of `Any`, a `T<Bool>` is not a subtype of `T<Any>`

Comment: What's the issue you're trying to solve with this? There are lots of work-arounds, but they're context dependent

Comment: Also, code that involves `Any` probably needs to be rethought. It is almost never the correct type (and commonly leads to surprises like this one).

Comment: I wan't to add a Class<T> into an array typed [Class<Any>]. What's work-around I can do?

Comment: How about adding A's template parameter P also to B (i.e. B<T, P>)? This way you restrict B to holding arrays of A<T, P> instead of A<T, Any> which most likely will make your life easier and for sure makes the compiler happy.